# Align items horizontally to equation above

Tags: beamer, equations, align, margins, itemize

I have an equation and a list explaining notation below.

Issue: I want the items to have the same margin at the left as the equation. See picture and MWE below.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{TWFE Specification}
        \begin{equation}
            y_{rt} = \sum_{t=2007}^{2019} \beta_t \times \mathbbm{1}[year=t] \times \mathbbm{1}[D=1] + \gamma_r + \lambda_t + \varepsilon_{rt}
        \end{equation}
    
        \bigskip
        {
        \small
        \begin{tblr}{
          colspec={
            @{}
            Q[
              preto={\hspace*{\leftmargini}},
              appto={}
             ]
            X
            @{}
          }
        }
          $y_{rt}$  & Outcome \\
          $D$  & $1$ treatment \\
          $\lambda_t$ & Year fixed effects \\
          $\gamma_r$ & Region fixed effects  \\
          $\varepsilon_{rt}$ & Error term\\
        \end{tblr}
        }       
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are anyway using a table for the explanation, why not make the whole equation part of the table?

```
\documentclass[10pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{TWFE Specification}
    
        \begin{tblr}{
          colspec={
            @{}
            Q[
              preto={\hspace*{\leftmargini}},
              appto={}
             ]
            @{}X
            @{}
          },
          column{1} = {mode=math},
          row{1} = {mode=math},
          row{2-Z} = {font=\small}
        }
          y_{rt} = & \displaystyle \sum_{t=2007}^{2019} \beta_t \times \mathbbm{1}[\text{year}=t] \times \mathbbm{1}[D=1] + \gamma_r + \lambda_t + \varepsilon_{rt}\refstepcounter{equation}\hfill (\theequation)\\[1cm]
          y_{rt}  & Outcome \\
          D  & $1$ treatment \\
          \lambda_t & Year fixed effects \\
          \gamma_r & Region fixed effects  \\
          \varepsilon_{rt} & Error term\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the equation in normal font size? I tried adding a normalsize manually but it did not change the display

 y_{rt} = & \displaystyle {\normalsize \sum_{t=2007}^{2019} \beta_t \times \mathbbm{1}[\text{year}=t] \times \mathbbm{1}[D=1] + \gamma_r + \lambda_t + \varepsilon_{rt}} \refstepcounter{equation}\hfill (\theequation)\\[1cm]

Comment: @Papayapap Sure, see my updated answer